# How to trigger notification hub from IoT hub?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, iot, azure-iot-hub, azure-notificationhub

I've been trying for hours to find some documentation on this but I can't seem to find anything!
I have a device connected to the IoT hub and I have notification working on the Notification hub.

But how can I connect these two?

I'm thinking of Functions, but I cant find any up to date documentation on how to do this
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Azure function as you mentioned. Refer the documentations on the IOThub [triggers and bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings) and [`NotificationHub`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-notification-hubs)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the help!
I figured it out using Azure functions v1.

I first got it to work using the HTTP trigger template in the azure portal, then in the 'intergrate' tab set the notification hub as output.

Then to trigger a notification you can use this code(anywhere in the index.js you'd like):

```
 context.bindings.notification = { message: "A package has been deliverd!"};
```

If anyone has questions feel free to ask!